# FuncAnimation to teach about SVD

Tags: image, matplotlib, animation

I have a question about animations. I would like to animate what it looks like to take an increasingly higher rank approximation of an image using the Singular Value Decomposition to show students an example of image compression. The animate function updates the array within `im` to a higher and higher rank approximation of the image `X` using the function  `X_reduced`.

```
import numpy as np 
from numpy.linalg import svd
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation, ArtistAnimation

# Read Images
image_path = 'images/bellie.jpg'
img = imread(image_path)
X = np.asarray(img).mean(axis=2)

# Do economy svd
U, S, V = svd(X, full_matrices=False)

def X_reduced(U, S, V, r):
    # Compute rank = r approximation 
    return U[:, :r] @ np.diag(S)[:r, :r] @ V[:r, :]

# Create figure and ax objects
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
X_0 = np.random.rand(*X.shape)
im = ax.imshow(X_0, cmap='gray')

def init():
    im.set_data(np.random.rand(*X.shape))
    return [im]

def animate(r):
    im.set_array(X_reduced(U, S, V, r))
    return [im]

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=100, interval=20)
plt.rcParams['animation.html'] = 'jshtml'
anim
```

Here is the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSj4G.gif). It's animating something, but not what I want. If I just plot a single figure with a few subplots for different ranks it does work. The result is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCIkv.png).

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,2)
ranks = [10, 25, 100, 200]
for i, ax in enumerate(axs.reshape(-1)):
    ax.imshow(X_reduced(U, S, V, ranks[i]))
```

Is there anyone that could help me out? Me and the students I am going to teach about the SVD will be very grateful!

Comment: use `im.set_data()` instead of `im.set_array()`

Comment: Yes! Turns out when I created im the first time, the boundaries for the minimum and maximum values were set based on the contents of X_0, which are of course in a different range compared to the X_reduced(U, S, V, r). The changing the first image line to im = ax.imshow(X_0, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255) solved to problem. Thanks for the suggestion though!